# The front impact sensor of my Jetta

Tags: vw, jetta, supplemental-restraint-system

The front impact sensor on my Jetta has its wires ripped out from a previous collision, is there a diagram that can help me rewire the harness?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you tried tracing the wires? each one will have a base color and a trace color...